# Spyder Won't Start: ConfigParser.ParsingError

Tags: python-2.7, spyder

I have installed `Python(x,y)-2.7.10.0` and am unable to start `spyder`. I did a couple of uninstalls and reinstalls but all in vain. This is what it shows on running '`spyder --show-console`' in cmd:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>spyder --show-console
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('spyder==2.3.5.2', 'console_scripts', 'spyder')()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2355, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\start_app.py", line 13, in <module>
    from spyderlib.config import CONF
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\config.py", line 718, in <module>
    subfolder=SUBFOLDER, backup=True, raw_mode=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\userconfig.py", line 215, in __init__
    self.load_from_ini()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\userconfig.py", line 260, in load_from_ini
    self.readfp(configfile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ConfigParser.py", line 324, in readfp
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ConfigParser.py", line 546, in _read
    raise e
ConfigParser.ParsingError: File contains parsing errors: C:\Users\Yamini\.spyder2\spyder.ini
        [line 19]: u'window/pref'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, StackOverflow is neither a forum, tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can help with [certain problems](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's your job to [put some efforts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) in the first place, including elementary [(re)search](https://www.google.com). Read [stack overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This error was fixed several years ago. Please uninstall PythonXY (which is very outdated and unmaintained now) and install an up to date version of Anaconda to get the fix for it.